# Using git clean to delete an untracked directory but not delete a subdirectory in that directory

Tags: git

I have the following:

```
C:\src\MyUntrackedDir
C:\src\MyUntrackedDir\SubDirToBeDeleted1
C:\src\MyUntrackedDir\SubDirToBeDeleted2
C:\src\MyUntrackedDir\SubDirToBePreserved
```

I want to be able to delete `C:\src\MyUntrackedDir\SubDirToBeDeleted1` and     `C:\src\MyUntrackedDir\SubDirToBeDeleted2`, but I do **not** want `C:\src\MyUntrackedDir\SubDirToBePreserved` to be deleted.

I thought that this should work:

```
git clean -f -d -x -e C:\src\MyUntrackedDir\SubDirToBePreserved
```

But that just ends up deleting everything in `C:\src\MyUntrackedDir`, including `C:\src\MyUntrackedDir\SubDirToBePreserved`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, the rules can be tricky. It's crucial to not run `git clean -f ...` blindly. Replace `-f` with `-n` first, and observe what would happen. If the output looks good, only then replace the `-n` with `-f`.

---

If a parent directory is selected for removal (`MyUntrackedDir` in your example), you cannot exclude items inside, they will all be removed. You could have preserved `SubDirToBePreserved` this way, for example:

```
C:
cd src
git clean -f -d -x -e MyUntrackedDir\SubDirToBePreserved MyUntrackedDir
```

This way, `MyUntrackedDir` itself is not selected for removal, only its contents, except the excluded `MyUntrackedDir\SubDirToBePreserved`.

Another alternative that would also work:

```
C:
cd src\MyUntrackedDir
git clean -f -d -x -e SubDirToBePreserved
```